# inspect element shows all elements at wrong position

Tags: wordpress, inspect-element

I am using Wordpress for my website. In the inspect element, all the page elements are at the wrong place. This problem is not only for my website, it's even for my Wordpress admin page.

Images of My homepage & Wordpress admin page

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is like asking someone to fix your car based on small, cropped photographs. Please include the code or link to live examples if you actually want to be helped.

Comment: That is my site: http://heliofizx.ir/

Comment: Looks completely fine to me in Chrome and Firefox my friend. It could be your browser or the machine itself.

Comment: Try minimizing and then maximizing the window, or dragging it to the top of the screen to maximize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your firefox browser is zoomed out. Press `ctrl+0` or go `view >> zoom >> reset`.